# Validating output from repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm pretty new in ASP.net, and im trying to validate some output from my SQL DB.

I want to test if "img" from my DB is set to somthing, and if, i wan't to output it.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="selectFromNews" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1.ProviderName %>"    
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [news] ORDER BY [time] DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:Repeater ID="newsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="selectFromNews" onitemcommand="newsRepeater_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="newsBox">
            <h1><%# Eval("title") %></h1>
            /* Test if "img" is set to somthing, and output it here, if not, do somthing else */
            <p><%# Eval("text") %></p>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I was thinking getting the data from behindcode, and then testing and sending an output back to a Literal, but dont know how i would access the repeaters data from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first add image control in Repeater as

```
    <asp:Image ID="ImageID" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("img")%>' Visible="false" />
```

then get this image control  in ItemDataBound event of repeater as

```
     protected void YourRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
      {
           if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
               Image ImageID= e.Item.FindControl("ImageID") as Image;
              // now play with your ImageID control..
            }
       }
```

Comment: Like this approach, but i get 
    Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
At: <asp:Image ID="newsImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Eval("img") %>" Visible="false" />

Comment: Found out... used: ImageUrl='<%# Bind("img") %>'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the use of `<% If ... Else ... End %>` blocks within repeaters is not available (trust me, I've wanted them so many times).

The easiest way of doing it is to call a code-behind function. For instance...

```
protected string MyFunction(RepeaterItem row)
{
   // return based on row.DataItem value
   return (row.DataItem.ImgExists ? "Image" : "No Image");
}
```

And then in the markup, you simply pass the `Container` object...

```
<%#MyFunction(Container)%>
```

**EDIT**... although for more complex visual changes, I would recommend the `ItemDataBound` solution that Tim and Usman (and Nikhil) provide

Answer (score 0):

You should use repeater's [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem ri = e.Item;
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)ri.DataItem;
    Panel Panel1 = (Panel)ri.FindControl("Panel1");
    // do your evaluation here according the values in the DataRowView     
    // use ri.FindControl("ID") to find controls in the Itemtemplate
}
```

aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" class="newsBox">
        <h1><%# Eval("title") %></h1>
         add controls here with runat=server, then you can find them from codebehind
        <p><%# Eval("text") %></p>
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: How would you get the value of "img"?
dr.somthing?
Or do i need to have it inside a controller?

Comment: If the image is runat=server and has the ID `Image1`(use the ASP.NET Image control) you can find it by using `(Image)ri.FindControl("Image1");`.

Comment: Problem is, that if i have runat=server on my img, or image controller. i can't add the image url to it in the repeater with Eval...?

Comment: @ChristianBekker: You can use an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) instead of an `img` (an `Image` will also be rendered as a html-img on client). Then you can change it's [`ImageUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx) property in `ItemDataBound`. But even if you want to stay with a html-img, you can add `runat="server"` and change it's `src` property in codebehind. My point is, you don't need to use `Eval` at all if you use codebehind.